# Extremely Small Output Weight Values in Echo State Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, weighted-regression

I have an echo state network that is producing an output weight matrix with extremely small output weights (on the order of 10^-200). Ideally, these weights should be within a more reasonable interval, say [-1,1]. Looking at neural network literature on ESNs and RNNs, some authors have tried ad hoc methods to manipulate the reservoir states. For example, one paper I came across simply multiplied all of the reservoir states by a scalar number, 8, to ensure that the output weight values of the output weight matrix were all within the interval [-1,1]. Are there any other common methods  in neural network literature to tune the reservoir such that the output weight matrix values are maintained within a reasonable interval?

Comment: Sounded like gradient issue. Maybe use a regularisation or similar settings in the optimisation.

Comment: sounds like a bug.